# Усреднение ключей Map с использованием lambda

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-stream, lambda

Есть исходный Map

```
Map<Double, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<>();
Map<Double, Integer> avgPairs = new HashMap<>();
pairs.put(4.2,4);
pairs.put(4.205,6);
pairs.put(7.33,67);
pairs.put(3.16,2);
...
```

Каким образом из исходных пар получить усредненный map, если значения ключей отличаются
друг от друга менее, чем на 0.5%?
Процентное соотношение между ключами находится по формуле
| (a — b) / [ (a + b) / 2 ] | * 100 %

Усредненный map - это среднее по ключам и сумма значений.
Желательно функционально.
Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
4.2025,10
7.33,67
3.16,2
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какой точный критерий включения ключей в одну группу. Для примера, есть ключи `0, 0.004, 0.008, 0.012, 0.016, 0.020, 0.024, 0.028`. Сколько, каких значений должно быть в результате и почему?

Comment: Имеется ввиду разница в % между каждым из ключей.
По формуле  | (a — b) / [ (a + b) / 2 ] | * 100 %
Из примера ключи 4.2 и 4.205 имеют разницу в 0.12%
Все ваши ключи достаточно далеки друг от друга по этому критерию и объединению не подлежат

Comment: ok, заменим на `1, 1.009, 1.018, 1.027, 1.036, 1.045, 1.054, 1.063`. Как быть теперь?

Comment: И еще, уточнения вопроса, как вот этот критерий, нужно добавить кнопкой "править" в текст вопроса.

Comment: В вашем примере разница в % между ближайшими числами в районе 0.8% и больше. Нужно усреднять при значении менее 0.5%
Например:
1.009, 1.0098, 1.006, 1.007 - все эти ключи надо усреднить и объединить

Comment: ok, пропустил деление на 2. Вы действительно не понимаете к чему я веду? Заменим на `1, 1.004, 1.008, 1.012, 1.016, 1.02, 1.024, 1.028`

Comment: Вы привели вырожденный случай, когда соседние элементы друг друга вымещают. Можно добавить условие, что если элемент входит в оба объединяемых диапазона, то оставлять его. Но эти числа имеют физический смысл и это крайне маловероятно. Лучше помогите с лямбдой)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132124/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-user188363).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попытаться написать некую функцию для группировки значений ключей входной мапы, на первом проходе сгруппировать "близкие" ключи, тогда получится условная мапа `Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry<Double, Integer>>>`, а на втором вычислить средние значения ключей и суммы значений по группам:

```java
Map<Double, Integer> avgPairs = pairs.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> (int)(e.getKey() * 10050/1000) // как пример, точность выбора не гарантируется
    )) // Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry<Double, Integer>>>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> 
            e.getValue().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getKey)),
        e -> 
            e.getValue().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
    ));
System.out.println(avgPairs);
```

Вывод:

```
73=[7.33=67]
42=[4.2=4, 4.205=6]
31=[3.16=2]
{3.16=2, 4.202500000000001=10, 7.33=67}
```

---

Несколько более точное решение, но использующее побочные эффекты -- генерацию предельного значения диапазона и идентификатор последнего подходящего диапазона.

Поскольку входной поток пар "ключ-значение" отсортирован, то при поступлении ключа, можно проверить, существует ли диапазон, если да, меньше ли входной ключ предельного значения и соответственно вернуть текущий индекс, или запомнить новое предельное значение и инкрементировать индекс.

*Однако, такое решение не будет гарантированно работать при использовании параллельных потоков по причине использования побочных эффектов.*

```java
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(-1);
Double[] max = new Double[1];
        
Map<Double, Integer> avgPairs = pairs.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> max[0] == null || e.getKey() > max[0] ? updateMax(e.getKey(), max, index).incrementAndGet() : index.get()
    )) // Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry<Double, Integer>>>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> 
            e.getValue().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getKey)),
        e -> 
            e.getValue().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
    ));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(max));  
System.out.println(avgPairs);
```

```java
static AtomicInteger updateMax(double d, Double[] max, AtomicInteger index) {
    max[0] = d * 1.005;
    return index;
}
```

Вывод (в тестовые данные добавлено `pairs.put(4.23, 9);`):

```
0=[3.16=2]
1=[4.2=4, 4.205=6]
2=[4.23=9]
3=[7.33=67]
[7.366649999999999] // 7,33 * 1,005
{4.23=9, 3.16=2, 4.202500000000001=10, 7.33=67}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это выглядит очень близко к правде!
Правда теперь ломаю голову как правильно написать Collectors.groupingBy(...),
так как ключи могут быть разных порядков, например 3.4E-8

Comment: Я добавил рабочий вариант, но он использует данные _вне_ стрима (побочный эффект)